# printing value of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var delivery_nums = ($("#delivery_num").val()).split(",");
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

for (var num =0 ; num < delivery_nums.length ; num++ ) {
    var input = '<div class="delivery-num-input">';
    input += "<input type='text'  pattern='[0-9]+'\
             class='form-control delivery_number_plus'\
             value='delivery_nums[num]'\
             placeholder='ex(1524587....)' required/>\
             <a href='#' class='remove_field btn btn-sm btn-danger'>\
             Remove</a></div>";
    $(wrapper).append(input); //add input box     
}
```

I want to make value=delivery_nums[num] to print the value of each item in loop it alays givs me num .

Answer (score 0):

You've got to break out of the script to use variables in the middle of a string like that.

```
input += "<input type='text'  pattern='[0-9]+'\
         class='form-control delivery_number_plus'\
         value='"+delivery_nums[num]+"'\
         placeholder='ex(1524587....)' required/>\
         <a href='#' class='remove_field btn btn-sm btn-danger'>\
         Remove</a></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to speared the string and variable

```
var delivery_nums = ($("#delivery_num").val()).split(",");
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

for (var num =0 ; num < delivery_nums.length ; num++ ) {
    var input = '<div class="delivery-num-input">';
    input += "<input type='text'  pattern='[0-9]+'\
             class='form-control delivery_number_plus'\
             value='"+delivery_nums[num]+"' placeholder='ex(1524587....)' required/>\
             <a href='#' class='remove_field btn btn-sm btn-danger'>\
             Remove</a></div>";
    $(wrapper).append(input); //add input box     
}
```